# Python - Printing Results from data.count to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use Tableau daily and Prep for ETL work but have made the leap to Python to start learning some actual code.

I am making a dashboard that looks at old computer games and the number of actions needed to complete the game through scraping walkthrough txt files. Now I was doing this in a hacky why in Prep and thought this was an opportune time to start learning python after a brief intro to it by a colleague.

Now so far I have managed to:

- convert my txt files into all lower case
- use data.count to get the counts of how many each search term has been used
- exported the results to a txt. file

Now the big issue I can't seem to get my head around properly is printing the results into a dataframe (pandas?) which I then can export more cleanly into Tableau. With a table I could also do the calculations I was going to do in Prep for practice too (fixed Max values etc.).

The code below has given me the results I expected (and better/quicker than with Prep!) within the console and the basic txt file:

```
#find Walkthrough files and convert them all to lowercase

file = open(r"C:\Users\melgaard\Documents\Dashboards (Fun)\Text file walkthroughs\DOTT Walkthrough2.txt", "r+")
lines=[line.lower() for line in file]
with open(r"C:\Users\melgaard\Documents\Dashboards (Fun)\Text file walkthroughs\DOTT Walkthrough2.txt", "r+") as out:
    out.writelines(sorted(lines))

import sys
sys.stdout = open(r'C:\Users\melgaard\Documents\Dashboards (Fun)\python_scrape.txt', 'w')

#get updated file for DOTT 
file = open(r"C:\Users\melgaard\Documents\Dashboards (Fun)\Text file walkthroughs\DOTT Walkthrough2.txt", "r")
#read content of file to string
data = file.read()

#get number of occurences of "Open"
occurences = data.count ("open")
print ('DOTT', "Open", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Give"
occurences = data.count("give")
print ('DOTT', "Give", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Close"
occurences = data.count("close")
print ('DOTT', "Close", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Pick Up"
occurences = data.count("pick up")+data.count("get")+data.count("take")
print ('DOTT', "Pick Up", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Look At"
occurences = data.count("look at")+data.count("look")
print ('DOTT', "Look At", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Talk To"
occurences = data.count("talk to")+data.count("speak")
print ('DOTT', "Talk To", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Use"
occurences = data.count("use")+data.count("press")
print ('DOTT', "Use", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Push"
occurences = data.count("push")
print ('DOTT', "Push", occurences)
#get number of occurences of "Pull"
occurences = data.count("pull")
print ('DOTT', "Pull", occurences)

sys.stdout.close()
```

**RESULTS**

- DOTT Open 26
- DOTT Give 9
- DOTT Close 1
- DOTT Pick Up 75
- DOTT Look At 3
- DOTT Talk To 17
- DOTT Use 146
- DOTT Push 9
- DOTT Pull 4

I got as far as this below for setting up a table but I couldn't get the results to "Print" into the table.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Game','Action','Value'])
print(df)
```

I know I can use a hacky way of adding a "," separator after each field above and let Prep do it's worth on it but I want to try and do all this in Python (as it's part of my own CPD really than actual work).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list. Then you append the `Game`, `Action`, and `occurrences` to the list. Finally create a dataframe using that list.

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
occurences = 2
data.append(['DOTT', "Open", occurences])
occurences = 5
data.append(['DOTT', "Pull", occurences])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Game', 'Action', 'Value'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Game Action  Value
0  DOTT   Open      2
1  DOTT   Pull      5
```